# JQuery Hotkeys - binding to multiple alphanumeric character combinations

Tags: jquery, hotkeys, jquery-hotkeys

I am using the latest version of [JQuery hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys).

The plug-in is fantastic and, in the main, does exactly what I need it to do.

However, I would like to bind to a combination of keys such as "A+H", for example:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'a+h', function(evt) { alert('hello world!'); }
```

This doesn't seem to work - has anyone acheived this succesfully? CTRL+A, etc. works, but it would be ideal if i could bind to combinations of alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: (In future when you ask a question and get an answer that is helpful you should click the "accept answer" button!)

Comment: I think what you are looking for would be called a 'key sequence'.  If you'd really like it it's something i've thought about adding to this library, a la mousetrap.js

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the code base and it looks like the way that plugin is programmed, it will not support the use case you're describing.  It lumps the modifier keys (<kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, etc.) together as a special case, which allows you to create combinations involving mod keys.  It doesn't support multiple standard keys, however.

I would suggest you ask the plugin developer to add this feature in a future release.  In the mean time, you can either adapt your goals to fit this plugin, try modifying the plugin yourself, or write custom code for this special case.

By the way, the code isn't particularly complicated so you should definitely take a gander.  Maybe you'll see something I don't.
[The plugin file](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js).

Comment: You're right, i just took a look and the source is very simple. I should have checked it first! I shall modify. Thanks for the quick and helpful answer.

Comment: No problem :)  If you like the answer please feel free to give me an up arrow and a check mark :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be possible to detect both keys since pressing any key will only fire off one event. Shift, alt, ctrl and other meta keys are a special case.

One solution would be to save the last key pressed then wait for the next one. I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/6nSfh/) of the code below:

```
var timer, last;
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    // Typing a then h will call the alert
    if (last == 65 && e.which === 72) {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
    last = e.which;
    // clear last value after 100 ms
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        last = '';
    }, 100);
});
```

Notice the last key is cleared after 100 milliseconds because without it, you could press "a" then wait something like 10 seconds, then press "h" to get the alert. Now the combination has to be pressed almost together (but the "a" has to be before the "h") - a slight modification would also allow the user to press "h" first then "a".

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you request but this works for a then h instead of a+h (which is awkard to do on your keyboard)

```
$(document).bind('keyup', 'a', function(){
    $(document).bind('keyup', 'h', function(){
        // do you shizzle
    });
});
```